# How to render two paths in an array with an only render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render, partial

I'm refactoring a view and built a class to return two paths.
They look like this:

```
["paths/path1", "paths/path2"]
```

and the view should present something like:

```
render "paths/path1"
render "paths/path2"
```

I'm doing this right now:

in my view:

```
<%= render @static_page.render_form_fields, f: f %>
```

ps - I tried to add .each and .map, but none worked

in my model:

```
def render_form_fields
  return self.is_default? ? FormPartialResolver.new(self).resolve_path : "admin/static_pages/form_partials/not_default_page_wrap"
end
```

in my resolver class:

```
class FormPartialResolver
  def initialize(static_page)
    @static_page = static_page
  end

  def resolve_path
    "PartialResolver::#{@static_page.slug.underscore.camelize}".constantize.new(@static_page).partial_path
  end

  def partial_path
    return ["admin/static_pages/form_partials/default_page_wrap", "admin/static_pages/form_partials/#{@static_page.slug.underscore}_wrap"]
  end
end
```

It's strange because when the model method returns a single path, the view renders right, but when it returns an array of two it gives me the following error:

'"admin/static_pages/form_partials/default_page_wrap"' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.

ps - when I added .each after the method call in the view render, it returned:

'#' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.

Comment: are you sure  that rendering multiple templates something that's supported?

Comment: I read something about it, so I think so (I'll keep searching this)
But if it's not, how could I render the elements of the array separately? I'm not very sure on how to get them...

Comment: Alias `to_partial_path` to `partial_path`; Have you tried using `render_to_string`? Otherwise I think you need to approach this differently. Rails doesn't have this kind of use-case in mind, and it's built for just about everything.

Comment: @EdiJunior well, you can't do multiple `render` calls from the same controlller action. You can try it, it will raise an error. That's why I question whether this is actually supported. You could link to the place you read it from.